# Using singleton in other thread

Tags: localization, internationalization, playframework, playframework-2.1

I should use the `play.i18n.Messages` localisation service in an other thread.

I can use the service in the other thread but the text value doesn't get returned just the given key as like the key would exist in the messages file.

I souppose that the `play.i18n.Messages` is a singleton. Is this the problem? Is there a way to get the original service which is working in the parent thread.